# Converting a string to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, for-loop

I have a string which I want to convert to a nested dictionary in Python.

Example Input :

```py
import copy
diff_str = "/pathConstraint/latency/latencyValue"
value = "low"
diff_arr = diff.split("/")
final_temp_dict = dict()
for elem in reversed(diff_arr):
    if len(final_temp_dict) == 0:
        final_temp_dict.setdefault(elem, value)
    else:
        temp_final_dict = copy.deepcopy(final_temp_dict)
        final_temp_dict.setdefault(elem, temp_final_dict)
    print (final_temp_dict)
```

While running this I face an error and I'm not getting the expected output.

The output needed is as a nested dictionary:

```py
{"pathConstraint" : {"latency" : {"latencyValue" : "low"}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following recursive function:

```
def string_to_dict(keys, value):
    key = keys.split('/')
    if len(key) == 2:
        return {key[1]: value}
    else:
        return string_to_dict('/'.join(key[:-1]), {key[-1]: value})
```

**Output:**

```
>>> string_to_dict(diff_str, value)
{'pathConstraint': {'latency': {'latencyValue': 'low'}}}
```

Note that this assumes that `diff_str` begins with a `/` character.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an iterative approach. Note `diff_arr[1:]` is used to exclude the empty string that is generated from splitting on the initial `/`.

```
diff_str = "/pathConstraint/latency/latencyValue"
value = "low"
diff_arr = diff_str.split("/")
for key in list(reversed(diff_arr[1:])):
    value = {key: value}
print(value)
```

Output

```
{'pathConstraint': {'latency': {'latencyValue': 'low'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter recursive approach:

```
def to_dict(d, v):
  return v if not d else {d[0]:to_dict(d[1:], v)}


diff_str = "/pathConstraint/latency/latencyValue"
value = "low"
print(to_dict(list(filter(None, diff_str.split('/'))), value))
```

Output:

```
{'pathConstraint': {'latency': {'latencyValue': 'low'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your function as little as possible, this should work just fine

```
import copy
def func():
    diff_str = "/pathConstraint/latency/latencyValue"
    value = "low"
    diff_arr = diff_str.split("/")
    final_temp_dict = dict()
    for elem in reversed(diff_arr):
        if elem == "":
            continue
        if len(final_temp_dict) == 0:
           final_temp_dict[elem] = value
        else:
           temp_final_dict = copy.deepcopy(final_temp_dict)
           final_temp_dict = {}
           final_temp_dict[elem] = temp_final_dict

    print (final_temp_dict)
```

However, there are much nicer ways to do something like this. See the other answers for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def convert(items, value):
    if not items:
        return value

    return {items.pop(0): convert(items, value)}


print(convert(diff_str.strip('/').split('/'), 'low'))
```